# Remove specific Javascript code that causes high CPU usage from Tumblr theme

Tags: javascript, html, css, tumblr, tumblr-themes

recently I decided to create a Tumblr using [this theme](https://zen-themes.com/free-tumblr-themes/level/)

I'm a Firefox user, and I noticed that this theme slows down the browser a lot. After some investingation and asking, the culprit seems to be the possibility to add an animated particle background that, even when disable, causes high cpu usage.
This particle function is inside a script called "[s.js](https://static.tumblr.com/j6tha7z/Jtmo5pjot/s.js)", that contains other part of the theme.

Is there any way to clean up the code from everything related to this particle background, and still leave the theme functional?

Thanks

Comment: That block of code is right at the bottom of the theme html, so you could just remove it. `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://static.tumblr.com/j6tha7z/Jtmo5pjot/s.js">` however it looks like a bundled file which handles lots of useful functions Imagesloaded, Isotope, Infinite Scroll so you might find that other parts of your theme don't work without it.

Comment: Oh, I see you want to edit that file and leave the other functions intact?

Comment: Exactly; if i remove the script from the html all I get is a blank Tumblr.

I tried by myself to edit s.js in order to remove the particle system, but I got the same result: a blank tumblr, because I know nothing about javascript so I think I removed other useful things!

Comment: Yeah you have your work cut out. I will try and write up an answer later, but it's relatively involved.

Answer (score 0):

OK

**Option 1:**

Search for all of the libraries that are being called from the js file you linked to [s.js](https://static.tumblr.com/j6tha7z/Jtmo5pjot/s.js) apart from ParticleJS.

1. Images Loaded: https://unpkg.com/imagesloaded@4.1.3/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js
2. Isotope: https://unpkg.com/isotope-layout@3.0.4/dist/isotope.pkgd.min.js
3. Infinite Scroll: https://unpkg.com/infinite-scroll@3.0.2/dist/infinite-scroll.pkgd.min.js
4. Fitvid: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fitvids/1.2.0/jquery.fitvids.min.js
5. Photoset grid: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/photoset-grid/1.0.1/jquery.photoset-grid.min.js
6. Magnific Popup: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js

*Caveat*, these are specific versions of each file and you could run into compatibility issues, if you need to link to a specific version.

Combine all the code from these files into a single file, then you could run it through a minifier: https://javascript-minifier.com/

For this solution to work you also need somewhere to host the file somewhere.

**Option 2:**

Link to all of the above files individually in your template. For example before the closing `<body>` tag you would need to add

`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/imagesloaded@4.1.3/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>`

... then add each of the other scripts. There may be a dependency order to these also, hopefully they are the same as in the header of the s.js file.

The drawback with this is instead of making a single http request to return a single js file, the template will request 6 separate js files (so this might be slower than the current system you have now).

**Option 3:**

If you can't host the file somewhere, you would have to actually copy the code from each js file into your template.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help;

I did what you listed in option 1, but still all i get is a fully blank Tumblr, as you can see here

https://themetestdjallo.tumblr.com/

I did something wrong, or maybe there's something that brokes by leaving this function? Could be in the html/css code of the theme?

Comment: Hmm, this is going to be tricky. Are there options in the theme to toggle masonry/infinite scroll for instance? You may have to activate those. Even so I think you could hit issues with the various files.

Comment: Yes there are, but  even if switched ff, the page remains blank. There are for ajax loading, infinite scroll and particle system